# Migrate from Youtube API v.2 to v.3 - very simple app

Tags: php, youtube-api

I used Youtube API v.2 for retrieving the list of my uploads.
The list was situated here:
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/blablabla/uploads?v=2&max-results=10&alt=json. I checked it every day and automatically posted new videos to my blog.

It was so brilliant and so simple that I was going to use it the next hundred years. But it does not work any more.

What's the simplest way to fix this with new API?

That's what I tried to do before posting this question:

- Registered new app in google developers console, turned on youtube api.
- Created OAUTH service account in credentials tab, got ClientId and P12 key.
- Downloaded google-api-php-client.
- Have written this code:

  ```
  $client_id = "blablabla.apps.googleusercontent.com";
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName("Youtube Exporter");
  $key = file_get_contents("key.p12");

  $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials($client_id,
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube",
      $key);
  $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
  $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);

  $service = new Google_Service_Youtube($client);
  ```
- The code throws an invalid_grant exception, I'm not sure if it's about the common auth or youtube service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a client ID or a P12 key; instead you just need a "key for browser applications" under the "public API access" section. IT's just a single key (not a pair), and once you have it, you can do the following:

1) You need to get your channel ID (Which is different from your username). This is a long string that starts with UC. If you can't find it, you can send a quick request to:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&forUsername={YOUR_USERNAME}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

The resultant json packet will have your channel ID in it.

With the key and the channel ID, you can very easily get your uploads list without any of the PHP code you're trying ... the PHP client will be very useful if you ever need to authenticate ohers to be able to do things like upload, etc. But for publicly readable data, you can just send a request to:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId={YOUR_CHANNEL_ID}&maxResults=10&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works exactly the same way it was in API v.2.